# cmake и opencv: установлено 2 версии, как Указать в проекте конкретную версию opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

Догадываюсь, что вопрос нубский. Но мне надо собирать проект то с одной версией opencv то с другой.. установил 4.5.4 и 4.8.0 но как теперь указать использовать заданную версию, а не последнюю установленную?

Comment: ¿Что значит *"установил"*?

Comment: По инструкции. В /usr/local присутствуют версии 4.5.4 и 4.8.0. Сначала ставил вторую, потом выяснилось, что нужна меньшая. Поставил поверх. Сейчас opencv у cmake - это версия 4.5.4:

Comment: find_package( OpenCV 4.8.0 REQUIRED )

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "OpenCV" that is compatible
  with requested version "4.8.0".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake, version: 4.5.4

Comment: ¿По какой инструкции? ¿Надеюсь вы сами ничего не копировали в /usr/local? А то многие делают #YOLO sudo make install...

Comment: /usr/local/lib содержит файлы обоих версий.

Comment: Билдил из исходников, по инструкции от opencv. Сначала версию 4.8.0, потом 4.5.4 .. в /usr/local/lib/cmake -- ф файлах описания везде указана версия 4.5.4 .. как тогда установить одновременно ОБЕ версии? Для решения задачи (перенос, поиск отличий) нужны обе.

Comment: @user7860670 А чем плохо ставить в `/usr/local`? Он же для того и нужен, в отличие от `/usr`.

Comment: Так оно и стоит в /usr/local как предписано в инструкции на opencv .. проблема в том, что там видны файлы компилированных библиотек от обеих версий, но cmake настырно не хочет переключаться с версии на версию и как его обучить .. хз. Про это и вопрос был. Есть решение, хоть какое-то?

Comment: Директива `find_package` подразумевает наличие чего-то, подпадающего под ожидаемое в соответствующем предустановленном скрипте cmake определение cmake-пакета OpenCV. Обычно на линуксе это может нормально прокатывать только в случае установки стоковых пакетов (типа -dev). В вашем же случае придется *самостоятельно* подгонять результаты сборки под это определение. Если повезет, то удастся обойтись малой кровью, задав только расположение файлов. Однако проще и лучше вместо `find_package` явно указать требуемые для сборки параметры.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Если реально *ставить*, а не просто наваливать файлы по папкам, как то обычно происходит при выполнении make install, то еще куда ни шло.

Comment: @user7860670 Поясните, как по вашему туда нужно правильно ставить?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну что-нибудь типа `apt-get install ...` или, на худой конец, `snap install ...`

Comment: @user7860670 Дык нет, системные пакетные менеджеры в `/usr/local` никогда ничего не ставят. По умолчанию, внутри одни пустые папки - как раз для того, чтобы туда делать грубый `make install` и не конфликтовать с пакетами.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это системные пакеты туда не ставятся, а так системным пакетным менеджерам ничего не мешает ставить в `/usr/local`.

Comment: @user7860670 То есть вы советуете запаковывать свежесобранную библиотеку в пакет, и уже его ставить в `/usr/local`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я советую вообще не заморачиваться с копированием собранных файлов в `/usr/local` или куда-либо еще, а использовать их там, где они лежат, во всяком случае, для целей разработки. Но если уж кому-то хочется добавить свои файлы в `/usr/local` или куда-то еще, то тогда да, лучше сделать полноценный пакет.

Comment: @user7860670 Ага, я обычно и не копирую.

Comment: Спасибо за развенутый диспут, но я так ничего и не понял пока что.. как в Cmakelist.txt указать заданную версию пакета? Или надо как-то по особому собирать обе версии, а не по инструкции от opencv?!? Мне-то что делать, если надо собирать одну и ту же прогу то с одной, то с другой версией?